# mysql: finding username

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed on my Mac and when i check the system preferences it shows that it is running.

When, while trying to follow a tutorial, I try to create a database

```
mysql> create database tinyclone;
```

I get this error

```
mysql> create database tinyclone;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tinyclone'
```

Before creating the database, the author of the book does

```
mysql –u <username> -p <password>
```

However, I don't know my username, and I'm not 100% sure I know my password either.

I tried to do

```
sudo create database tinyclone;
```

and I got a different error message. Not sure what the problem with my syntax was

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sudo create database tinyclone' at line 1
```

Question, so that I can follow along with the book's author, anyone know how I can find out my mysql username and password?

Comment: try `mysql -u root -proot` or `mysql -uroot`

Comment: The user should be root. Have you set any password for root?
`mysqladmin -u root password 'password here'`

Comment: Have you seen this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html?

Comment: Not to sound greedy, but if you're going to accept, an upvote is generally considered nice.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get this error
>
> mysql> create database tinyclone;
>
> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tinyclone'

You're not logged in as any user (hence the ''@'localhost' bit).  As others have suggested, try doing `mysql -uroot -proot` or `mysql -uroot`.

> However, I don't know my username, and I'm not 100% sure I know my password either.

There is (almost) always a 'root' user created by default, usually with no password, unless you specified one when initially installing/configuring mysql.

> I tried to do
>
> sudo create database tinyclone;
>
> and I got a different error message. Not sure what the problem with my syntax was
>   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sudo create database tinyclone' at line 1

`sudo` is not an SQL command.  You cannot use it inside mysql.  Instead log into sql with the 'root' user.

Also, please note that the mysql root user is **not the same as your computer's root user.**

Answer (score 0):

C.5.4.1.3. Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

You miss CREATE privilege.

Connect as a root user, create new user and grant CREATE privilege -

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user1'@'localhost' = PASSWORD ('your_password');
GRANT Create ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost'
```

Then connect as 'user1'@'localhost' -

```
mysql> --user=user1 --p=your_password
```

...and create new database -

```
CREATE DATABASE tinyclone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you install mySQL you're prompted for password for the admin user (root) if you skipped it the only user currently available for mysql is root and that user doesn't have password enabled (which isn't a great idea for production environment)
So, what you should do is:

```
~$ mysql -u root
```

then

```
create database tinyclone
```